# pyobjc webuidelegate functions not called

Tags: webview, pyobjc

I have linked my WebView UIDelegate to BrowserWindowController in interface builder, which is my delegate that implements the webuidelegate functions. In my browserwindowcontroller class, I also do:

class BrowserWindowController(NSWindowController):

```
webView = objc.IBOutlet()

def windowDidLoad(self):
    self.webView.setUIDelegate_(self)

def webViewDidStartLoad_(self, webView):
    print "DID LOAD START"

def webView_didFailLoadWithError_(self, webView, error):
    print "ERROR"

def webViewDidFinishLoad_(self, webView):
    print "DID FINISH LOAD"

 def webView_shouldStartLoadWithRequest_navigationType_(self, webView, request, nav_type):
    print "LOAD REQ"
```

None of the last four functions, which are part of the WebUIDelegate, get called. I even tried doing (what is for a formal protocol, even though this is informal):
class BrowserWindowController(NSWindowController, WebKit.protocols.WebUIDelegate):

But that does not work. I have implemented the WebView WebPolicyDelegate the same way and it does work. Why doesn't WebUIDelegate work? I have linked it the way I have read in the docs. Am I missing something for this informal protocol?

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's documentation(1) the delegate protocol does not have a selector named webviewDidStartLoad:.  The selector is is the "UIWebViewDelegate" protocol, but that's used on iOS, not OSX.

1:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. Even so, I implemented all of the webuidelegate functions and none of them handle a button click that does window.open(url, "_blank"), where url is a file that must be opened. The same button click will open http://www.google.com with no event sent, but it will not open my file's url. Any ideas? I already have the policydelegate implemented and it does not respond to the open.

Comment: A WebPolicyDelegate should do the trick:  <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001912>